# How to stop Excel VBS running if cell has contents

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a spreadsheet which auto-fills date/time in column B when there are contents entered into column C. There is a risk however of double clicking or making changes in the cell will update the date and time, I don't want it to do this if it has already been populated.

What do I need to add to my code to stop the macro running IF the cell has contents?

This is the coding I used:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C8:C27")) Is Nothing Then

        With Target(1, -0)

            .Value = Now

            .EntireColumn.AutoFit

        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking if the cell in column B is empty before writing the date into it is fairly straightforward. Inside your `With` statement just check if the value of the cell in B is blank and exit the sub if there is something in it. Otherwise run through your code to write the date to the cell.

```
With Target(1, -0)
    If .Value <> "" Then Exit Sub

    .Value = Now

    .EntireColumn.AutoFit

End With
```